# Django Oscar - In checkout process payment details process is getting skipped

Tags: django, django-oscar

I have small eCommerce project in django-oscar. 
In my checkout process **payment details process** is getting skipped, i have not yet forked the oscar checkout app still getting this error.

my console responce

```
[17/Dec/2018 18:37:57] "GET /checkout/payment-method/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Why is it redirect to **payment preview page?**

Any solution on it or suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subclass oscar.apps.checkout.view.PaymentMethodView according to [a comment the source](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/checkout/views.py#L356):

```
class PaymentMethodView(CheckoutSessionMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # By default we redirect straight onto the payment details view. Shops
        # that require a choice of payment method may want to override this
        # method to implement their specific logic.
        return self.get_success_response()
```

(If you have already created a subclass, post your code)